# compile-time constraints on the order of function composition in scala

Tags: scala, types, function-composition

I'd like to define some functions for processing natural language text. Each of these functions adds some "annotations" to the text, e.g.:

```
class Annotation(val begin: Int, val end: Int)
class Sentence(begin: Int, end: Int) extends Annotation(begin, end)
class Token(begin: Int, end: Int) extends Annotation(begin, end)
```

So I might have a Tokenizer function that adds Token annotations, a SentenceSegmenter function that adds Sentence annotations, etc. These functions have some constraints on the order in which they can be run. For example, the Tokenizer might require Sentence annotations, so it would have to be run after the SentenceSegmenter. In this case, I'd like to get a compile error if I accidentally compose these functions in the wrong order. So `sentenceSegmenter andThen tokenizer` should compile, but `tokenizer andThen sentenceSegmenter` should not.

Below is my attempt. I defined a special container type for the text, where the type parameter specifies (via compound types) what annotations have been added to the text, and then the functions specify their type parameters appropriately to ensure that they can't be run until their prerequisites are part of the compound type.

```
trait AnalyzedText[T] {
  def text: String
  def ++[U](annotations: Iterator[U]): AnalyzedText[T with U] 
}

val begin: (AnalyzedText[Any] => AnalyzedText[Any]) = identity
def sentenceSegmenter[T]: (AnalyzedText[T] => AnalyzedText[T with Sentence]) = ???
def tokenizer[T <: Sentence]: (AnalyzedText[T] => AnalyzedText[T with Token]) = ???

// compiles
val pipeline = begin andThen sentenceSegmenter andThen tokenizer
// fails to compile -- good!
//val brokenPipeline = begin andThen tokenizer andThen sentenceSegmenter
```

So far, so good. The problem arises when I try to actually define one of the functions. For example, I'd like to define `tokenizer` something like:

```
def tokenizer[T <: Sentence]: (AnalyzedText[T] => AnalyzedText[T with Token]) =
  text => text ++ "\\S+".r.findAllMatchIn(text.text).map(m => new Token(m.start, m.end))
```

But the Scala compiler can't figure out how to infer the type argument for the `++` method, and unless I manually specify the type parameter, `text.++[Token](...)`, this produces the error:

```
type mismatch;  found: Iterator[Token]  required: Iterator[Nothing]
```

Is there a way to get this type parameter to be inferred? Or, alternatively, am I thinking about the problem wrong? Is there a better way to capture these kinds of function-composition constraints in Scala?

Comment: [More isolated version of the problem](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/5962424).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks [an awful lot like a bug](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/5962424). In the meantime there's a very simple workaround—just define your processor as a method and omit the return type:

```
def tokenizer[T <: Sentence](text: AnalyzedText[T]) =
  text ++ "\\S+".r.findAllMatchIn(text.text).map(m => new Token(m.start, m.end))
```

Now you can define your `pipeline` in exactly the same way and eta-expansion (§6.26.5) will turn the method into a function.

---

As a footnote: the weird part is that the following is just fine, given the definition of `tokenizer` above:

```
def tokFunc[T <: Sentence]: (AnalyzedText[T] => AnalyzedText[T with Token]) =
  tokenizer _
```

I glanced at [the issue tracker](https://issues.scala-lang.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) but didn't find anything that was obviously relevant. It might be worth digging around some more and filing an issue or emailing [one of the lists](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/199) if you have the time.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, your workaround seems to solve my problem just fine. Interesting that explicitly declaring the type is the source of the problem... I did go ahead and file an issue (https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7647). We'll see if it's a bug or a feature. ;-)